# MiniZinc confused by derived enums

Tags: enums, minizinc

I am trying to extend the SEND+MORE=MONEY model from [section 2.2.2](https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.7.4/en/modelling2.html#global-constraints) of the MiniZinc tutorial to solve cryptarithms of variable length (both in terms of how many things are being summed and in the words themselves), and in order to make the data format nicer I tried to use enums.

I finally have a model file that compiles, which looks like the following:

```
int: base;
set of int: DIGITS = 0..base;

enum Letters;
enum Letters_or_zero = C(Letters) ++ {zero};
array[Letters_or_zero] of var DIGITS: letters;

set of Letters_or_zero: Firsts;

int: nsum;
int: ndig;
set of int: NSUM = 1..nsum;
set of int: NDIG = 1..ndig;
array[NSUM, NDIG] of Letters_or_zero: sums;

int: tdig;
set of int: TDIG = 1..tdig;
array[TDIG] of Letters_or_zero: tot;
```

I set it up like this so that I could write the input data something like this:

```
base = 10;
Letters = {S, E, N, D, M, O, R, Y};
Firsts = {S, M};
nsum = 2;
ndig = 4;
sums = 
        [| S, E, N, D,
         | M, O, R, E |];
tdig = 5;
tot = [M, O, N, E, Y];

constraint alldifferent(letters[C(Letters)]);
constraint forall(l in Firsts) (letters[l] != 0);
constraint letters[zero] = 0;

constraint
        sum(s in NSUM, d in NDIG) ( pow(base, ndig - d) * letters[sums[s, d]] )
        = sum(d in TDIG) ( pow(base, tdig - d) * letters[tot[d]] )
;

solve satisfy;
```

The `Letters_or_zero` construction is specifically to allow for zero-padding of the values in `sums`, so that for example SHIRT+TSHIRT=CLOTHES could be represented with

```
sums =
     [| zero, S, H, I, R, T,
      |    T, S, H, I, R, T |];
```

Before I included the "or zero" component and just declared everything in terms of the enum `Letters`, this all worked fine. But now I'm getting errors saying that `Firsts`, `sums` and `tot` are of the wrong type, because they're of type `Letters` rather than `Letters_or_zero`. If I use the constructor function to wrap all the elements, e.g. `Firsts = {C(S), C(M)};` then it works, but then the data declaration becomes messy.

Is there a nice way to set this up so that I can keep some of the niceness of my data format? My one thought is to change `sums` from a 2D array to a set of arrays, so that they can be of variable length and I can drop the "or zero" fix, but I'd like to know if there's another approach that would be more suitable.